# React 18 - Infinite rendering when passing a state variable for lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, zustand

With react 17 via lazy loading, i was dynamically loading one of three components according to the selected language (state variable from zustand store).
The import depends on that variable:

```js
const MyComponent = lazy(() => import(`component-${language}.jsx`))
```

After migrating to react 18, the component is in infinite rendering.

I imagine it's related to the new automatic batching feature.

Somebody can help ?
Best Regards

- create a function outside the component to receive the variable as prop from the component or as direct import from the store but the error persists.
- instead of the state variable i tried a getter from the store but with no success.
- tried to use useState and useEffect replacing the state variable on the import but also with no success.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case, I'm trying to import a form and the application keeps "suspending":

```ts
const ImportForm = lazy(() => import(`brokers/${broker?.importPath}/Form`));
```

Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

The infinite loading is due to the fact that import a statement under React.lazy triggers a rerender of the component. In my case I was calling the lazy function inside suspenses which triggered a infinite loop due to the lazy function causing a re render each time.

I fixed it by moving the import lazy call in the same component as Suspense.

Check the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-merkle-e04e4w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This fixes it! thanks for the sandbox with the comments too!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<React.Suspense fallback="..."><MyComponent /></React.Suspense>
```

Comment: A suggestion to try something is not an answer but a comment.